# Haskell: Default module prefix

Tags: haskell

If have a Stack Haskell project called `MyProject` that contains the following modules:

```
src\
   Foo1
   Foo2
   Bar\
       Foo3
```

I would like to add a project prefix to all of the module names to help me distinguish them from other imported modules from other packages, eg `MyProject.Bar.Foo3`

I know I could move the contents of `src` into a folder `MyProject` and then prefix all the modules with `MyProject.`, but is there a way to do this with the cabal file, eg `project-prefix=MyProject`, or other solution that will give me the same effect, without having to restructure the project files?

Comment: Not as far as I know; you could maybe add a symlink `MyProject → .` t the `src` folder. And see what tools break that naively traverse the directory tree :-)

Comment: If you don’t want to break tools, add a symlink `MyProject → ../src` to a new directory `real-src` and use that as the `hs-sources` option in the `.cabal` file.

Comment: While you can probably use a symlink as suggested, I would just create the `src/MyProject` directory and move everything into it. This is how cabal expects it, and how every other package does it, so why not just do it?

Comment: I now realise that the best solution is to just follow the convention and move my source files into the ```MyProject``` folder.